# How to configure IBM CIO dedicated cloud to serve vue.js projects

Tags: vue.js, deployment, ibm-cloud, devops

I am developing a front end project using the vue-js framework, and I want to deploy it on IBM's CIO organization dedicated cloud.  I am using the webpack framework, so I believe I only need to have two files served, the build.js file (which is compiled on an 'npm run build' command), and the index.html file.  However, how do I configure my toolchain in the cloud console to only serve these two files?

I have a toolchain setup that automatically deploys code when I push to the corresponding github repository.  For the purposes of collaboration, the github repository needs to contain the entire project's code, but for the purposes of deployment, I only want two files to be served.  How do I enable this configuration?